# Website doesn't display properly

Tags: google-chrome

The website I'm developing suddenly stopped working properly. The images on my Homepage appear sliced and in weird places (however when inspecting source and hovering over certain elements, the highlighted content seems to be in the right place), some hover on effects don't work and some text doesn't render.

Everything works properly in all other browsers except for Google Chrome. I cannot think of any other thing I've updated in the source code than executing svginjection plugin.

I uploaded my backed up files that used to work before, but the problem still occurs. It doesn't show up on every single computer, just on some (and I've checked it on multiple machines, both - Mac and Windows).

Just to clarify, I did clear the cache, I did check in the Incognito mode, I did restart my computer. None of these helped. I'm also 80% sure that problem only occurs on computers, on which this website was previously opened (the pattern I noticed after making around 10 tests at work).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight, so after going through all my files, trying to disable multiple options, etc... Everything is fixed now. If you do have similar problem, go through your css files and disable all webkit powered transforms and transitions, cause apparently enough is enough and if you have too many, Chrome just won't handle it. I managed to still reuse some of them, so... Must have caused some glitch in the matrix and that's why it all got messed up. For weirdly positioned images check z-index of parent container.